# Some one can explain to me how this code executes ? I still mess up with recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

That output is supposed to be 4,3,2,1 right?

```
def test(x): 
 if x > 0 :
  test(x - 1)
  print(x)
test(4)
#output => 1
#output => 2
#output => 3
#output => 4
```

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied and pasted to test and debug. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Additionally, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as [ask]. Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: You are not allowed to drastically change a question after you have received answers. If you are trying to cope with a question ban, you are only digging yourself into a deeper hole by trying to circumvent the limitations on your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what a call stack is. Code is being pushed to the call stack and poping as we go. This is where recursive calls are done. see this for reference
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/

test(4) is generating test(3), test(2), test(1), and pushing to the call stack. As we know Stack is FILO (First In Last Out). Last pushed recursion instruction will pop and execute first resulting print of 1. then 2,3 and lastly 4.